# Tela de Login com Banco de dados C#!

Tags: c#

Eae, pessoal! Então... eu sou bem novato em programação e estou tendo uns problemas com a tela de login com banco de dados. O código não dá nenhum erro, mas é como se não existisse o cadastro do usuário no SQL server, tentei todos os 5 cadastros que existem e nada, só recebo a mensagem de que os dados estão incorretos, parece que a variável valor não muda seu valor. Será que poderiam me ajudar ?!

```
public void Logar()
    {


     string con = " server = DESKTOP-6BAVUH0; Database = Cadastro; Trusted_Connection = true";
    SqlConnection Conex = new SqlConnection(con);

    string coman = @"SELECT Count (*) FROM usuario WHERE Login = @nome AND Senha = @password AND [E-mail] = @email" ;

        string nome= textBox1.Text, password = textBox2.Text, email = textBox3.Text ;
        try

        {


            SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(coman, Conex);

            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome",nome);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password",password);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
            Conex.Open();

            int valor = (int)comando.ExecuteScalar();
            if (valor > 0)
            {
                Logado = true;
                MessageBox.Show("Logado com sucesso. Sejam bem-vindo!");

                this.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                Logado = false;
                MessageBox.Show("Dados incorretos!");

            }
        }

        catch (SqlException erro)

        {

            MessageBox.Show(erro + "Na conexão com o banco de dados");
        }

        finally
        {
            Conex.Close();


        }

    }
```

Grato se puderem  ajudar!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O código não tem nenhum problema. Você deveria checar a tabela "usuário", as colunas(campos) nome, password e e-mail podem conter espaços, e maiúsculas e minúsculas influenciam na pesquisa.

Use o Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio para testar as pesquisas, veja o exemplo:

```
SELECT [Login]
      ,[Senha]
      ,[E-Mail]
  FROM [Cadastro].[dbo].[Usuario]
  where [Login] = 'John' and
    Senha = '123456' and
    [E-mail] = 'john@google.com'
```

Antonio

Comment: Pô, cara! Muito obrigado mesmo! De alguma forma a outra form que eu tinha criado para fazer o cadastro do usuário estava acrescentando o espaço antes do nome, senha e e-mail por causa do meu código. Eu já arrumei aqui isso, não acredito que fiquei 2 dias nisso, hahaha. Muito obrigado mesmo, confrade!